# Kendo MVC Grid paging buttons not changing results displayed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo Grid. The paging numbers are ok, items per page is ok, but when I press on page number the results in grid isn't changing, all results are shown in first page. Please help here.

Below is my code:

```js
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#invoices-grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                data: @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Invoices)),
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        fields: {
                            JobNumber: { type: "string" },
                            CustomerName: { type: "string" },
                            DepartmentName: { type: "string" },
                            DateInvoice: { type: "string" },
                            ValidDays: { type: "number" },
                            Delivery: { type: "string" },
                            IsPayed: { type: "boolean" },
                            Payed: { type: "number" },
                            Status: { type: "boolean" },
                        }
                    }
                },
                @*type: "json",
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("List", "Finances"))",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: additionalData1
                    },
                },
                schema: {
                    data: "Data",
                    total: "Total",
                    errors: "Errors"
                },*@
                error: function(e) {
                    display_kendoui_grid_error(e);
                    // Cancel the changes
                    this.cancelChanges();
                },
                pageSize: 20,
                serverPaging: true,
                serverFiltering: true,
                serverSorting: true
            },
          
            columns: [
                {
                    field: "JobNumber",
                    title: "@T("gp.Invoice.Fields.JobNumber")",
                    template: '#= JobNumber #'
                },
                {
                    field: "CustomerName",
                    title: "@T("gp.Invoice.Fields.CustomerName")",
                    template: '#= CustomerName #'
                },
                {
                    field: "DepartmentName",
                    title: "@T("gp.Invoice.Fields.DepartmentName")",
                    template: '#= DepartmentName #'
                },
                {
                    field: "DateInvoice",
                    title: "@T("gp.Invoice.Fields.DateInvoice")",
                    template: '#= DateInvoice #'
                },
                {
                    field: "ValidDays",
                    title: "@T("gp.Invoice.Fields.ValidDays")",
                    template: '#= ValidDays #'
                },
                {
                    field: "Delivery",
                    title: "@T("gp.Invoice.Fields.Delivery")",
                    template: '#= Delivery #'
                },
                {
                    field: "Payed",
                    title: "@T("gp.Invoice.Fields.IsPayed")",
                    template: '#= (Payed == 2) ? "Комп." : ((Payed == 1) ? "ДЕ" : "НЕ") #'
                },
                {
                    field: "Id",
                    title: "@T("Common.Edit")",
                    width: 100,
                    template: '<a href="Edit/#=Id#">@T("Common.Edit")</a>'
                },
            ],
            pageable: {
                refresh: true,
                pageSizes: [5, 10, 20, 50]
            },
            editable: {
                confirmation: false,
                mode: "popup"
            },
            scrollable: false,
           
            selectable: true,
            change: function(e) {
                var selectedRows = this.select();

                var jobId = parseInt($(selectedRows).data('job-id'));
                var jobItemId = parseInt($(selectedRows).data('job-item-id'));

                var result = $.get("@Url.Action("SideDetails", "Production")/" + jobItemId);

                result.done(function(data) {

                    if (data) {
                        $(".job-edit .jobItemDetails").html(data);
                    }

                });
             
            },
           
            rowTemplate: kendo.template($("#invoiceRowTemplate").html()),
        });
    });
</script>
```

```csharp
protected virtual void PrepareInvoiceFinanceListModel(FinanceListModel model,FormCollection form/*,string SearchJobItemNumber*/)
{
    var customers = model.SearchCustomerId;
    var isChecked = model.IsChecked;
    var searchString = model.SearchJobItemNumber;
    var IsChecked1 = model.IsChecked1;
    // searchString = model.SearchJobItemNumber;/* "001/2016";*/
    //var searchString = model.SearchJobItemNumber;
    //searchString = "091/2016";
    
    if (model == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("model");

    var finishedJobs = _jobService.GetJobsByHasInvoice(false);

    finishedJobs = finishedJobs.OrderByDescending(x =>
        {
            var firstOrDefault = x.JobItems.FirstOrDefault();
            return firstOrDefault?.DateCompletition ?? new DateTime();
        }).ToList();

    foreach (var job in finishedJobs)
    {
        var jobModel = job.ToModel();
        model.FinishedJobs.Add(jobModel);
    }

    var jobsBycustomers = finishedJobs.GroupBy(x => new { x.CustomerId, x.Customer.Name }).Select(x => new JobCustomersModel()
    {
        CustomerId = x.Key.CustomerId,
        CustomerName = x.Key.Name,
        JobsCount = x.Count(),
    });

    model.FinishedJobStatus = new JobStatusesModel()
    {
        Status = _localizationService.GetResource("gp.jobs.whitout.invoice"),
        Value = (int)JobStatusEnum.Finished,
        Count = finishedJobs.Count,
        CustomersJobs = jobsBycustomers.ToList()
    };

    var invoices = _invoiceService.GetAllInvoices(searchString, isChecked, IsChecked1, customers);
    foreach (var invoice in invoices)
    {
        var inv = invoice.ToModel();
        // var a = invoice.Payed;
        model.Invoices.Add(inv);
    }
    
    /////////////////////             ////////////////////////
    //var allCustomers = _invoiceService.GetAllCustomers(customers);
    //foreach (var customer in allCustomers)
    //{
    //    var cust = customer.ToModel();
    //    model.SearchCustomerId = customer.CustomerId;
    //    model.Invoices.Add(cust);
    //}

    var invoiceByCustomer = invoices
        .GroupBy(x => new { x.CustomerId, x.CustomerName })
        .Select(x => new JobCustomersModel()
        {
            CustomerId = x.Key.CustomerId,
            CustomerName = x.Key.CustomerName,
            JobsCount = x.Count(),
        });

    model.InvoiceStatus = new JobStatusesModel()
    {
        Status = _localizationService.GetResource("gp.jobs.with.invoice"),
        Value = (int)JobStatusEnum.Finished,
        Count = invoices.Count,
        CustomersJobs = invoiceByCustomer.ToList()
    };

    var latestOffers = _offerService.GetLatestOffers(0, 10);
    foreach (var offer in latestOffers)
    {
        var offerModel = offer.ToModel();
        model.LatestOffers.Add(offerModel);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently server operations are enabled...

```
serverPaging: true,
serverFiltering: true,
serverSorting: true
```

... but the `transport` configuration is commented out. This is the cause of the problem.

If you want to use server operations, then configure the dataSource `transport`. Otherwise, use local data binding and disable server operations, as in this example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/styles/kendo.default.min.css">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="invoices-grid"></div>

    <script>
      $(function() {

        var d = [];

        for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
          d.push({Id: i, CustomerName: "CustomerName " + i});
        }

        $("#invoices-grid").kendoGrid({
          dataSource: {
            data: d,
            schema: {
              model: {
                id: "Id",
                fields: {
                  CustomerName: { type: "string" }
                }
              }
            },

            error: function(e) {
              display_kendoui_grid_error(e);
              // Cancel the changes
              this.cancelChanges();
            },
            pageSize: 20,
            //serverPaging: true,
            //serverFiltering: true,
            //serverSorting: true
          },


          columns: [

            {
              field: "CustomerName",
              title: "gp.Invoice.Fields.CustomerName",
              template: '#= CustomerName #'
            },
            {
              field: "Id",
              title: "Common.Edit",
              width: 100,
              template: '<a href="Edit/#=Id#">Common.Edit</a>'
            },

          ],
          pageable: {
            refresh: true,
            pageSizes: [5, 10, 20, 50]
          },
          editable: {
            confirmation: false,
            mode: "popup"
          },
          scrollable: false,

          selectable: true,
          change: function(e) {
          }


        });
      });

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can i somehow to add here my own paging method in this code?

Comment: I've edited question,add data from controller,this is data from controller which is kendo filled from, but i dont know how to add it as a local source as in your example

Comment: otherwise when I add data transport popup is not firing, i cant understand here what is the problem

Comment: this is workig but now my button inside grid  column isnt invoking javascript function which is in kendo template.Button is working till the moment when i click page number